# Ajax Timer: Execute only 5 times

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ajax, vb.net

I have a ajax Timer control. It adds “+” to the text value of a label. This timer should work only five times with an interval of “1000” – i.e, only five “+” should be available. After that, the lblPostbackType
 Should be updated with the count. How do I achieve it?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
static int partialPostBackCount = 0;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).IsInAsyncPostBack)
        {
           partialPostBackCount = partialPostBackCount + 1;
           lblPostbackType.Text = "Partial Postback:: " + partialPostBackCount.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            lblPostbackType.Text = "Full Postback";
        }
    }

}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "+";
}
}
```

And the designer code is

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
<asp:Timer runat="server" ID="Timer1" Interval="1000" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" />

 <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblPostbackType" >SAMPLE</asp:Label>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="TimePanel" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: You really want to postback to the server just to add a `+` to a label?! Learn javascript! ;)

Comment: I am just learning Ajax. Assume that in real scenario I need to get a value from Server

Comment: @Lijo: please consider selecting the answer, if it is..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    if (partialPostBackCount > 5 )
        {
           lblPostbackType.Text = "Partial Postback:: " + 
                                   partialPostBackCount.ToString();
           //Timer1.Enabled = false; //if you don't want it to continue
        }
        else
        {
            partialPostBackCount = partialPostBackCount + 1;
            Label1.Text = Label1.Text + "+";
        }

}
```

*static variables are not recommended..

keep the Page_Load event method clean..